# What does this symbol mean in this ladder logic rung?

Tags: ladder

[image: symbol that needs clarification]

Trying to figure out what this symbol means, for context here's the rung on the ladder logic diagram that it was taken from.
[image]

Comment: You appear to be talking about ladder logic.  If so, could you _edit your question to say so_?  I would go as far as to suggest that your title should say "ladder logic" in it somewhere.

Comment: @TimWescott I'm only focused on the symbol meaning. I put the schematic I took it from so that it could probably offer additional meaning. You're certain I should mention ladder logic?

Comment: @SRR Ladder logic uses a *very* different set of symbols than anything else in electrical engineering, so yes, you should definitely mention the context in which you see the symbol.

Comment: What country or region did this schematic originate from? Is it a fluidic (pneumatic or hydraulic) system? The symbol suggests some kind of limit function.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Jamaica. HV422 is a pneumatically actuated valve

Comment: You should add the info from your comments to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol relates to an SPST toggle / rotary switch.